# How to prove the non-existence of solution of a contour problem with ordinary differential equation methods?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let
$$\begin{cases}
-y^{''}(x)-y(x)= \sin(x), \forall x \in [0, \pi] \\
y(0)=y(\pi)=0
\end{cases}\label{eq1}\tag{1}$$

Prove that it has no solution.

It is a non-homogeneous linear ordinary differential equation of the second order, so the general solution can be written as: $ y (x) = y_ {h} (x) + y_ {p} (x) $ where

$y_{h} (x) $ is the solution of the homogeneous equation $ -y^{''} - y = 0 $, which is $ y_{h} (x) = c_{1} \cos (x) + c_{2} \sin (x) $.

$ y_{p} (x) $ is the particular solution that satisfies the non-homogeneous equation $ -y^{''}(x) -y(x) = \sin (x) $, then we assume it as $y_{p} (x) = A \cos (x) + B \sin (x) $, deriving and substituting we get that: $ -y_{p}^{''} (x) -y_{p}(x) = \sin(x) \longrightarrow A \cos(x) + B \sin(x) - A \cos(x) - B \sin (x) = \sin(x) $,
i.e. $ 0 = \sin (x) $
but this is not true for all $ x \in [0, \pi] $.

Would this prove that $ (1) $ has no solution? 
And if not, can you tell me how to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ y_{p} (x) = Ax \cos x + B \sin x \rightarrow A= 1/2 $ and $B=0$

Answer (score 0):

The method of undetermined coefficients demands to add a factor $x$ in the case of resonance,
$$
y_p(x)=x(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x))
$$
with
$$
-y_p''(x)-y_p(x)=2A\sin(x)-2B\cos(x)\implies A=\frac12, ~~B=0.
$$
In total with the left side boundary condition
$$
y(x)=\frac12x\cos(x)+C\sin(x),
$$
but at the right boundary $0=y(\pi)=\frac{\pi}2\cos(\pi)=-\frac{\pi}2$ is impossible to satisfy.

Comment: The rule is to take the multiplicity $m$ of the left side and the degree $d$ from the right side and set up a term $x^mq(x)e^{\lambda x}$ where $q$ has undetermined coefficients and degree $d$. In your example $-y''-y=x\sin x$ you would have to try $y_p(x)=x((A_0+A_1x)\cos x+(B_0+B_1x)\sin x)$. Using symmetry one can eliminate the odd terms directly, that is $A_0=B_1=0$.

Comment: Hmm! My example is $-y''-y= \sin x$ no $-y''-y= x \sin x$

Comment: $y_h$ remains as homogeneous or complementary solution as it was, it is only the particular solution that needs a different approach.

Comment: Why $y_{p}(x) = x (c_{1} \cos(x)+c_{2} \sin(x))$  ? if  if the term no that does not make my problem homogeneous is $ \sin(x)$ no $x \sin(x)$

Comment: Compute the solution for $\sin(ax)$ on the right side and then the limit $a\to 1$. You should get a difference quotient.

Comment: But $ y_ {p} (x) $ cannot be like this because $ Bx \sin (x) $ is not a solution to the inhomogeneous problem.

Comment: It could be, ... if you put a term $\cos x$ on the right side of the DE. But what about the conclusion $B=0$ is so complicated to understand?

Comment: Of course you can add arbitrary parts of the homogeneous solution to a particular solution to get another solution of the inhomogeneous equation.